# sharepoint 2010 switching multiple content list forms in a single page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have 4 different lists setup by using multiple content lists so end-up with 4 different forms. Is there any way to make one default form for all in a single page and switching them by using maybe a dropdown list?

Please advise

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So you have 4 lists, each with their own new form, and you want a single page to show all 4, but control which one is showing based on a dropdown?

Comment: Hi David, yes correct..

Answer (score 1):

This should be feasible using iframes in the same manner SharePoint does. Your dropdown list would need some JavaScript to handle showing and hiding the iframes, and each iframe might look something like

`<iframe class="ms-dlgFrame" id="form1" src="http://site/lists/listName/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1" frameBorder="0" style="width: 620px; height: 650px;">`

That should get you what you need.

Comment: thanks David, is there any easier way like embed the "Current view" dropdown in the form ribbon (pop-up dialog)? currently the "Current view" is not visible in the pop-up dialog and if I access it via "Forms Web Part --> New Form --> Form (Edit) ribbon" I can see the "current view" but it is grayed out.

Comment: The Current View is only available for list views. I'm not sure I follow where you're seeing it.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for reply.. it is similar like this http://blog.concurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/InfoPath_Figure11.jpg cheers

Comment: Ah yes. So that is being used to switch views so you can edit the pages accordingly. It's not available elsewhere.

Comment: Awesome! Please make sure to mark this question as answered for the benefit of the community. Happy SharePointing!